# Extracting the first line in group

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have a huge file containing a list of directories and files (generated by a `find`). It's contents is something like this:

```
./12345/a1abeff031.dat
./12345/a1abeef03a.dat
./12345/a1abefa032.dat
./12346/c3abeff031.dat
./12346/a1abeff031.dat
./12347/a2abeff021.dat
```

So, I just need one file of each directory (the order doesn't matter), the desired result is this:

```
./12345/a1abeff031.dat
./12346/c3abeff031.dat
./12347/a2abeff021.dat
```

How can I get this using shell/awk/grep/sed or other command line tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following once.

```
awk -F'/' '!a[$2]++' Input_file
```

Comment: Yes!, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl

```
perl -F"/" -lane ' print unless $kv{$F[1]}++ '
```

with the given input

```
$ cat leonard.txt
./12345/a1abeff031.dat
./12345/a1abeef03a.dat
./12345/a1abefa032.dat
./12346/c3abeff031.dat
./12346/a1abeff031.dat
./12347/a2abeff021.dat
$ perl -F"/" -lane ' print unless $kv{$F[1]}++ ' leonard.txt
./12345/a1abeff031.dat
./12346/c3abeff031.dat
./12347/a2abeff021.dat
$
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;s/^(([^/]*\/[^/]*\/).*)\n\2.*/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

Open a window of 2 lines throughout the file and remove any duplicate directories printing only the first.

To print the last file in a set of duplicates, use:

```
sed -E 'N;/^([^/]*\/[^/]*\/).*\n\1/!P;D' file
```